# setting more space between controls in a flowLayout

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

C# WinForms: 
when we drop controls inside a flowlayout, horizontally, is there a way to set more space than its default between controls?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the value of the [Control.Margin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) of the contained controls.

Comment: margin or padding? I was playing with Padding just now, looks like it is doing the job.

Comment: @BDotA: Padding is for the space within the container control between its border and its content.